# Switching between keyboards with Bluetooth keyboard with cmd + space shortcut

Tags: bluetooth, 7.0-nougat, external-keyboard, gboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I use an **Apple Bluetooth Keyboard** with **[External Keyboard Helper Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.apedroid.hwkeyboardhelper&hl=en)** as my keyboard of choice on an **Android 7.0 Tablet**.

I use **Gboard** when I'm not using the external keyboard.

When the external keyboard is connected, the input method in use can be switched by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.

But instead of switching between all the installed soft keyboards, it switches between **handwriting recognition** and **External Keyboard Pro**.

On the other hand, if I manually switch to Gboard with the **keyboard selector icon**, the <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> shortcut switches between the default **Android keyboard** and **Gboard** only.

> Is there a way to configure the **language switch** to choose between **External Keyboard Pro** and **Gboard** **only**?
>
> Or make it switch between all available input methods?

I tried disabling the **handwriting recognition** input method and now, when **External Keyboard Pro** is selected, <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> does nothing.

I tried disabling the **Android Keyboard (AOSP)** and it automatically disables **Gboard** as well.

Comment: Any luck with that? Seems like a gaping hole in Android TV. Almost as if its not used in any multi-lingual locations..

Comment: No luck. I'm now using a different tablet running Android 9 and the issue is still there.

Comment: Yeah, That's the dead end i got to as well. Thanks.